# How to avoid hibernate of a hyper-v guest vm

Tags: shutdown, hyper-v

I have a Hyper-V guest VM which runs Ubuntu. This VM is self-encrypted using LUKS. Now, when I shutdown the (Windows) host, my VM gets hibernated, eg its state saved to a file. This bypasses all my security efforts i did inside the VM because the (virtual) RAM contents is never encrypted.
Encrypting the VM on host-side is only half an option, because I have reasons to not disable LUKS inside the guest. The result would result in a double encryption.

In the settings of the VM, I explicitly activated "hard shutdown" instead of hibernation. Unfortunately, this option doesn't seem to be considered.

[image: stop action setting of my VM (unfortunately in German)]

The guest extension is active and enabled

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-VMIntegrationService -VMName myvm

VMName Name                               Enabled PrimaryStatusDescription SecondaryStatusDescription
------ ----                               ------- ------------------------ --------------------------
myvm   Gastdienstschnittstelle            True    OK
myvm   Takt                               True    OK
myvm   Austausch von Schlüsselwertepaaren True    OK                       Die Protokollversion der auf dem virtuell...
myvm   Herunterfahren                     True    OK
myvm   Zeitsynchronisierung               True    OK
myvm   VSS                                False   OK
```

How can I force an automatic hard or soft shutdown of my VM if the host shuts down?

Comment: Turn on the third Shut down option. Before that you must have integration services installed.

Comment: @Wasif_Hasan Nope, same result. "Shutdown" selected in the VM stop action settings but the VM still hibernates